# Grep Sed with bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, cut

I'm trying to achieve the following using bash and sed where the file containing below strings

```sh
qa2.test.m.xyz.com

554
1723
21

qa88.test.nj.xyz.com

1723
554
21
443
80

qa2.lite.xyz.com

554
1723
21

qa2.www.nj.xyz.com

80
443
1723
21
554

tadmins.xyz.com


meadmin.xyz.com


real.xyz.com


responsible.xyz.com

554
1723
21
80
443
```

should look like this but if list of port number after the domain name is not present just echo the domain name

```sh
qa2.test.m.xyz.com
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:554
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:1723
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:21

qa88.test.nj.xyz.com
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:1723
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:554
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:21
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:443
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:80

.
.
.
.
like wise.
```

I don't know which delimiter should I choose and which logic should I write.

Comment: I don't think `sed` can do this - your operations aren't constrained to a single line, you need to store the last domain in memory. You'd need something like `awk`.

Comment: oh okay, I think have to write bash script for the same, I was wondering if it is possible with one liner or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with GNU sed:

*parse.sed*

```
# Assume first line holds the first domain address and save it `h` to
# hold-space, print it `b` and move on to next input line `b`
1 { h; p; b; }

# When domain line found, save it to hold-space `h` and print it with a gap 
/^[[:alnum:]]+(\.[[:alnum:]]+)+/ { h; s/^/\n/p; }

# When we have a number, fetch domain name from hold-space `G` and
# swap them around with `s///`
/^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
  G
  s/([^\n]+)\n(.*)/\2:\1/p
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -nEf parse.sed infile
```

Output:

```
qa2.test.m.xyz.com
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:554
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:1723
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:21

qa88.test.nj.xyz.com
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:1723
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:554
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:21
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:443
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:80

qa2.lite.xyz.com
qa2.lite.xyz.com:554
qa2.lite.xyz.com:1723
qa2.lite.xyz.com:21

qa2.www.nj.xyz.com
qa2.www.nj.xyz.com:80
qa2.www.nj.xyz.com:443
qa2.www.nj.xyz.com:1723
qa2.www.nj.xyz.com:21
qa2.www.nj.xyz.com:554

tadmins.xyz.com

meadmin.xyz.com

real.xyz.com

responsible.xyz.com
responsible.xyz.com:554
responsible.xyz.com:1723
responsible.xyz.com:21
responsible.xyz.com:80
responsible.xyz.com:443
```

Comment: Well this one is great and it works amazingly, I was trying to do the parsing with this logic but couldn't able to achieve it, can you help me out why? following is my code

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ports=$(cat port-scan-clear.txt |grep -v ".com"|sed '/^$/d' |sort -u)
urls=$(cat port-scan-clear.txt|grep ".com"|sort -u)


echo "${ports[0]}"

for ((i=0;i<="${#urls[@]}";i++))
do
for ((j=0;j<="${#ports[@]}";j++))
do
echo "${urls[$i]}"":""${ports[$j]}"
done
done

```

Comment: @m4xx: either edit your question with this new information or post a new question

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `awk` for this.

```
awk '
    # Skip blank lines
    $0=="" { next }

    # If the value is numerically zero (it's probably a string) so save the domain
    # Print a blank line to separate from the previous group (unless first line)
    !($0+0) { if (domain>"") { print "" }; domain = $0 }

    # If the value is numerically non-zero prepare to print the domain and this port number
    $0+0>0 { $0 = domain ":" $0 }

    # Print whatever we've got
    1
' input_file
```

Output (truncated)

```
qa2.test.m.xyz.com
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:554
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:1723
qa2.test.m.xyz.com:21

qa88.test.nj.xyz.com
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:1723
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:554
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:21
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:443
qa88.test.nj.xyz.com:80

qa2.lite.xyz.com
qa2.lite.xyz.com:554
...
```

Comment: Hey this works like a charm!